# how can I write to a read only file from the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm implementing a system call in a 2.6.22 kernel. In my system call I obtain a file descriptor like this:

```
fd = sys_open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0544);
```

However, I get a negative number (-13) for fd when filename points to a read only file. The problem is that I need to write to filename, even if it's read only or owned by another user.

So my question is this, how can I write to a read only file from the kernel?

And yes, I've read the post in linux journal that says writing to a file from the kernel is a bad idea.

I still need to do it.

Comment: If your question is really "how can I write to a read only file from the kernel?" than that should be the title of your question, not "sys_open returns negative file descriptor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative number isn't a file descriptor, it's an error code. Specifically it will be the negative version of one of the `errno.h` error numbers.

In this case as you have `-13` you are looking at error 13 which is `EACCES` meaning that you don't have permission to write to the file.

Comment: Your answer started a chain reaction which allowed me to work out the issue in my code that was preventing it from working.